# Convex Hull of points on the $n$ Sphere

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose we have a finite set $\{b_1,\dots,b_m\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ laying on $S^{n-1}$. Moreover we have an $\epsilon>0$ and an $a\in S^{n-1}$ such that $\overline{B_\epsilon(a)}\cap conv\{b_1,\dots,b_m\}\neq\emptyset$. Is there a function $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that $\overline{B_{\delta(\epsilon)}(a)}\cap\{b_a,\dots,b_m\}\neq\emptyset$?

In three dimension it can be seen that $\delta(\epsilon)=\sqrt{2\epsilon}$ does the job. It is of particular interest whether $\delta$ depends on the dimension of the euclidean space.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\delta = \sqrt{2\epsilon}$ works in any dimension.

If $a, b \in \mathbb S^{n-1}$ with $\|b - a\| > \delta$, $$a \cdot b = \frac{1}{2} \left(\|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 - \|b - a\|^2\right) < 1 - \frac{\delta^2}{2} $$
If that is true for all $b_m$, then you also have $a \cdot b < 1 - \delta^2/2$ for any linear combination of the $b_j$.
Then $\|a - b \| \ge a \cdot (a - b) > \delta^2/2$.